# How can I get my Telegram auto-forward bot to forward without quoting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a bot that automatically forwards messages from channel A to group B and I created this bot with Node.js. The bot forwards messages but shows that it is quoting, how can I make it appear as if it was shared without showing it, in summary with no quote?

The code:

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');

const sourceChannelId = CHANNEL_ID;
const targetChannelId = CHANNEL_ID;

const bot = new TelegramBot('BOT_TOKEN', { polling: true });

bot.on('channel_post', (msg) => {
  if (msg.chat.id === sourceChannelId) {
    bot.forwardMessage(targetChannelId, sourceChannelId, msg.message_id);
  }
});
```

I don't know how to do this, I tried ChatGPT but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to forward messages from one chat to another on Telegram, the Telethon library provides a seamless solution for handling this task. The `client.send_message(chat, message)` function can be effectively used for forwarding messages without quoting, allowing for forwarding of various kinds of content such as files, videos, and etc.

I do not know  node.js . but here is an example code for python for how to retrieve message entities from a source channel, and subsequently forwarding them as copies to another chat (channel, group, or user):

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

# Establish a client connection using your credentials
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

Source_id = -1001444411118  # Replace with your source chat's username or ID
Source_entity = client.get_entity(Source_id)
Source_id = Source_entity.id

Destination_id = '@my__channel'  # Replace with your destination chat's username or ID
Destination_entity = client.get_entity(Destination_id)
Destination_id = Destination_entity.id

# Fetch the latest 3 messages from the source
msgs = client.get_messages(Source_id, limit=3)
msgs = msgs[::-1]  # Reverse the order of messages

# Forward each message to the destination
for msg in msgs:
    client.send_message(Destination_id, msg)
```

In the above code, ensure to replace api_id and api_hash with your Telegram API credentials. Additionally, substitute the source and destination IDs with the actual IDs or usernames of your respective channels or groups.

Hope this helps!